# does Lyapunov exponent depends on initial state?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Does Lyapunov exponent $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\lim_{|\delta Z_0|\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{t}\ln\frac{|\delta Z(t)|}{|\delta Z_0|}$ depends on initial state $Z_0$?

I'm asking this question since I think the exponent is trying to say that if we slightly perturb the initial state, how the deviation between perturbed solution and unperturbed solution grows over time. I think the different initial state we perturbed, then the different value for this exponent will be obtained.

p.s. I found in other document, it says the definition above is actually **maximal** lypunov exponent, I am wonder why it is? does **maximal** comes from $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}$?

Comment: It is maximal in the sense that a power iteration will produce the maximal eigenvalue. If you propagate a frame of perturbations, keeping it orthogonal at all times, you can also get the lower exponents, see for example https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/36013/numerical-computation-of-lyapunov-exponent

Comment: Thank you very much! could you elaborate more about *a power iteration will produce the maximal eigenvalue*? what is power iteration, does it mean the mapping in the sense of discrete time $x(n+1)=f(x(n))$? and why it is related to eigenvalue?

Comment: The power iteration for a matrix, $w_{n+1}=Ax_n$, $x_{n+1}=w_{n+1}/\|w_{n+1}\|$, converges, under the right conditions, to the eigenvector for the largest eigenvalue. The practical computation of the Lyapunov exponent does something similar, only that the matrix $A$ is the Jacobian of the ODE function, "gliding" along the solution path. So in principle one could replace the hard average against a gliding average, where then indeed the initial point has exponentially decreasing influence.

Comment: not sure whether i understand, so... lyapunov exponent does depend on the initial state?

Comment: If the attracting set has multiple components, then the LEC can be different for each, and the initial point selects the component. If there is only one component, then something like the Cesaro mean applies, the influence of any fixed initial phase falls with $1/t$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. If I understand correctly, did you mean: Maximal Lyapunov exponent indeed depends on the initial state, and if the phase space has only one global attractor, then all trajectories including the perturbed ones and the unperturbed one will converge to that attractor, thus the value of LEC would be the same. If the phase space has multiple local attractors, for example, 3 attractors, then the maximal lyapunov exponent have 3 values, each value corresponds to each attractor.

Comment: Yes, a dependence in that sense, where there are multiple "stable" attractors.

Comment: Understand, thank you very much!!